# How to Make Android game on google play store install on windows option on

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, store, playback

i need to know how to make android game on google paly store ( install on windows option allowed )

see attachment .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvsZH.png)

i am trying to make my games playable on windows platform , not just android  , my question is how to enable this option on the google developer console for each game .

Comment: Have you read the Google doc about Google Play Games on Windows? https://developer.android.com/games/playgames/overview